# MySQL combine n tables

Tags: mysql, merge, myisam

I have n (source) tables with the same structure that each have few million rows. Each of these table receives new data from different sources on a regular basis.

(Ex: Sales table. Each store have its own sales table. There's 1000 stores selling hundred of thousands items each day. How would you combine those tables?)

I would like to merge them in one summary table. I would like the changes from any of the source tables to be reflected on the summary and changes on the summary to be reflected on the appropriate source table.

(Ex: Sales table. When new sales occurs, the summary table is updated. If a changes to the sale is made in the summary table, it is reflected on the appropriate store table.)

I can see three solutions.

1.Create an event/trigger that would refresh my summary tables at a given time or after an insert/update/delete.
Something like:

```
#Some event triggers this
DROP TABLE table_summary;
INSERT INTO table_summary
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablen...
```

The downside here, I believe, is performance, I do not think I can afford to run this query every time there is an `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` on one of the table.

2.Create a view.

```
CREATE VIEW table_summary AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2;
#This query takes 90s to complete
```

Performance wise, I have the same kind of problem as with the solution #1

3.Create an `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` trigger for each table. That's a lot of triggers and MySQL limit to one per table. I started that way but the code scaffolding to maintain appears impressive and likely hard to maintain.

I am sure there's a better way I have not think of.

Comment: Why you do not save all of (`INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE`) statements for each table, Then apply those statements on the summary table ?

Comment: Seems to me you need some kind of data cube,not possible in mysql

Comment: My question is: why do you need a summary table. That will help in answering your question because, if it is for the sake of getting reports, how often do you need those? For instance if they are weekly you can do DML on each table separately and at the end of the week do the union on the tables.

Comment: @wajeeh I am a not sure how I would do that as there is multiple computers writing independently on those tables. Plus, I still need to monitor the changes to the summary table

Comment: @Mihai Could you expend on the data cube?

Comment: @Rubbic I am looking at a fairly short time resolution (in terms of seconds, maybe few minutes). Pretty much as soon an event occurred I would like to be able to access the records through the summary table.

Comment: Here is an example in sql server,it`s just an elaborate way to meaningfully present huge amounts of data https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216365(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: "Summary", to me, means a table with fewer rows and subtotals from COUNT(*), SUM(...), etc.  Is that what you mean?  Or do you really mean the `UNION` of separate tables?

Comment: @RickJames I really mean `UNION` of separate tables

Comment: OK `UNION`.  Why do you need a single table with redundant data?  Why not simply do the `UNION` whenever you need all the data?